# Turning on dormant Windows 2008 Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

We have a domain controller (one of three) that has been off for several months. It has no FSMO roles, but it is the WSUS server.

Best case scenario, we turn on and it replicates with the other two and everything is fine, right?

What are some other scenarios that I should be aware of? I could just decommission it, if there could be bad outcomes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It has likely tombstoned and will not replicate with the other DCs in your domain. The proper thing to do is a metadata cleanup for the domain controller, reinstall Windows, and reconfigure WSUS.

If you're on Server 2003, you'll need to use `ntdsutil` to clean up the DC metadata. If you're on 2008 or later, you can just delete the computer object from ADUC and then delete the NTDS object from Sites and Services for the dead DC.

You can check the tombstone lifetime using dsquery or PowerShell. In PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADObject -Identity "CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com" -properties tombstonelifetime
```

Obviously fill in the appropriate DN for your environment.

If your DC has been offline for *less time* than the returned value for the tombstone period (probably either 60 or 180 days) then it's safe to turn back on as is.

Answer (score 4):

If it is within the default tombstone lifetime of 180 days, should be ok.  Additionally, 2008 and newer have 'Strict Replication Consistency' enabled by default.  This means that if the dormant dc attempted to replicate a changed object that had been deleted, the other dc would deny inbound replication from that dc until the lingering object had been removed.

If replication does shut down due to lingering objects, repadmin can be used to correct the issue.

Where this can go sideways is if it were upgraded from 2003, and Strict Replication was never enabled.  In that scenario, its possible that lingering objects could be reintroduced to the directory.

Answer (score 2):

If it's been turned off shorter than the tombstone lifetime then you should be OK to turn it back on. If it's been turned off longer than the tombstone lifetime or you're unable to tell then DO NOT turn it back on. In that case, use NTDSUTIL to remove it from AD.